# How should I conduct a double time tempo change?

Tags: rhythm, time-signatures, tempo, conducting

I am working on a pop arrangement. It starts out in a simple 4/4 quarter note equals 90 and then a tempo change doubles it. Now it's eight notes = 90 and quarter = 180.

- Do I change the time signature to 4/8?
- When I conduct if I lose my tempo while going slow then doubling is that just practice work or can changing the meter help me?

Comment: Why not just score it in half time, rather than doubling the tempo? Problem solved, song is still at 90bpm, everybody's playing 16ths instead of 8ths.

Answer (score 1):

Not 4/8 for a pop song.

DOES it go into a fast 4 or a moderate 2?  If the former, write 4/4 quarter=180.  If the latter, write cut time half=90.